# asp.net core 2.0 - multiple projects solution docker file

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

[asp.net core 2.0 and docker for linux]

I am completely new to docker and trying to figure out how to use docker in a case where i have a solution with 2 projects. All tutorials i've seen show with single project.

So, if someone could show step by step solution i would really appreciate it.

i have a solution structure like:

```
Solution.sln
|______WebAPIProject.csproj
|______ClassLibraryProject.csproj
```

In Visual studio, i've added docker support to solution and got these files:

Under WebAPIProject, it created this **Docker file**:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPIProject.dll"]
```

then, under separate docker-compose 'project' i've got:

**docker-compose.ci.build.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-2.0
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./Solution.sln && dotnet publish ./Solution.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

and **docker.compose.yml** file

```
version: '3'

services:
  WebAPIProject:
    image: WebAPIProject
    build:
      context: ./WebAPIProject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I am sure its something trivial with paths but i am just pretty lost with it all so if someone could shed a bit of a light on it?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution?
For me adding Docker support causes an error when it tries to create the image.
Thanks

Answer (score 53):

While I understand that dotnet core isn't specific to Windows and not everyone is going to be using Visual Studio, there's this neat feature that Microsoft has included inside Visual Studio (Tried it in 2017).

1. Right click on the Web Project.
2. Select Add.
3. Then "Docker Support". This will automatically fetch multiple projects into the container.

If you have multiple Web Projects, repeat the step individually for each.

Here's the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1#existing-app

If you happen to run with any issues when running the Docker container, try deselecting `Hyper-V Services` in "Windows Features" (Search for `Windows Features` in Start Menu), selecting again, and then restarting your computer.
Check [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2105).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately when I used this command I got an error simmilar to this issue - https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1922

Comment: Disabling the Hyper-V feature worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: That's a life saver tip. Two days struggling on this issue. Thanks very much.

Comment: I had to drag and drop the Dockerfile in the same folder containtin the .sln. Thanks!

Comment: The option is missing for class libraries. :-/

Answer (score 49):

I finally found a way how to built solutions with docker.

**IMPORTANT: For this to work, you have to put the Dockerfile file into the same location where the solution file is**

I've just created a docker file with the following content:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Solution.sln ./
COPY ClassLibraryProject/*.csproj ./ClassLibraryProject/
COPY WebAPIProject/*.csproj ./WebAPIProject/

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ClassLibraryProject
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

WORKDIR /src/WebAPIProject
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPIProject.dll"]
```

Note that I think you may have to respect project build dependencies but I don't know really.

Sample call to build:

```
sudo docker build --no-cache -t webapi:dev .
```

Sample call to run:

```
sudo docker run -d=false -p 8080:80 --name webapi webapi:dev
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: On docker build well I get this error  `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder953792128/MyProject.sln: no such file or directory` , any suggestions?

Comment: Are dockerfile and solution file in the same folder?

Comment: No, it is like this  `project1.sln, project1folder -> Dockerfile, project1.csproj `

Comment: That is the cause why docker can't find your sln file. The paths are relative seen from the docker file location. Please copy the docker file into the solution folder.

Comment: If I move the docker file into the solution folder -- then the build and publish from Visual Studio fail.  So that's a terrible solution.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same problem and all other solutions didn't fit my so I worked out my own.
I feel that bellow steps are legible, but if you're new to Docker, I explained it line by line in my [blog post dedicated to new Docker users](https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/multi-project-dotnet-core-solution-in-docker-image) (so you could understand precisely what is going on in this *Dockerfile*).

1. Keep ***Dockerfile* in project directory** (which is, in my point of view, better than keeping it next to solution file, because you can have more than one Docker image per solution).
2. Configure *Dockerfile* as follows:

```dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish PROJECT_NAME -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/PROJECT_NAME/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PROJECT_NAME.dll"]
```

3. **Move *.dockerignore* file to solution directory** - that's required, because Docker CLI takes *.dockerignore* file only from root directory of the build context (as [documentation says](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)), but it's also convenient, because you have one, common set of ignore rules for all projects (similar to *.gitignore* file), which is easier to maintain.
4. Run **build command from solution directory**, pointing to *Dockerfile* in project directory, and setting current directory (*.*) as build context (to have access to all projects):

```bash
docker build -f PROJECT_DIRECTORY/Dockerfile -t IMAGE_NAME .
```

5. Run container as usual, for example:

```bash
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name my-app-name IMAGE_NAME
```

Comment: The fourth point is exactly what I need! Thank you! For my case, I generated the dockerfile via VS "Add Docker Support". After that, I just execute the docker build command from my solution directory, pointing to the targeted project's Dockerfile path.

Comment: tometchy , you're genious thank your for the solution i have been tried and it founds the other csproj files thank you !

Answer (score 15):

This links to [an amazing post](https://andrewlock.net/optimising-asp-net-core-apps-in-docker-avoiding-manually-copying-csproj-files-part-2/) about how to tackle this issue.

He mentions putting all your code in a `src` directory. I didn't so that, and this is the file i came up with: (The key is the `for file` part. I'm sure it's not the best dockerfile otherwise; tips are welcome.)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ./*.sln ./

COPY */*.csproj ./
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ${file%.*} && mv $file ${file%.*}; done
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PersonalSiteApi.dll"]
```

Answer (score 4):

## As of 2022 docker-compose 3.9

After few attempts, I managed to do it this way:

Project hierarchy:

```
MoulaTracker/
|- MoulaTracker.Core/    # <- PROJECT 1
|- MoulaTracker.Api/     # <- PROJECT 2
|- Dockerfile.Core
|- Dockerfile.Api
|- docker-compose.yml
|- MoulaTracker.sln
```

The project `MoulaTracker.Api` is dependent of `MoulaTracker.Core`

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  moula-tracker-core:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.Core
  moula-tracker-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.Api
```

**Dockerfile.Api**:

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.409 AS build-env

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
WORKDIR /MoulaTracker.Api
COPY ./MoulaTracker.Api .
COPY ./MoulaTracker.Core ../MoulaTracker.Core
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.0 AS runtime

WORKDIR /MoulaTracker.Api
COPY --from=build-env /MoulaTracker.Api/ ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/MoulaTracker.Api.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir /output

# Copy project and publish

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/YourProjectName
RUN dotnet publish --configuration Debug --output /output

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5001

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /output .
EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourProjectName.dll"]
```

This is a Docker configuration that worked for me. This was an ASP.NET Core 2 WebApi project with many child project references.

```
Then run it using  docker run -d -p 8080:5001 --name some-name yourpojectname
```

Hope this helpes someone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install docker desktop as administrator
2. Run Docker desktop as administrator
3. Move your sln file to projects folders (project folder level)
4. right click to projects go to Add option -> Docker support ->  Container Orchestrator Support and choose linux OS and click OK
5. it will generated DockerFile and docker composer files
6. open cmd as administrator and go to sln file path
7. run docker-compose build
8. after docker-compose up