# How make Docker find referenced projects on build?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, project, dockerhub

How should I reference a project in project file so Docker build finds the projects?

**Project file**:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Assets.Core\Assets.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Creator.Components\Creator.Components.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LC.Components.Core\LC.Components.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LC.Components\LC.Components.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /DIRPATH
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Creator.Demo.dll"]
```

**Output**:

> Determining projects to restore...   Skipping project
> "C:\Assets.Core\Assets.Core.csproj" because it was not found.
> Skipping project "C:\Creator.Components\Creator.Components.csproj"
> because it was not found.   Skipping project
> "C:\LC.Components.Core\LC.Components.Core.csproj" because it was not
> found.   Skipping project "C:\LC.Components\LC.Components.csproj"
> because it was not found.   Skipping project
> "C:\Assets.Core\Assets.Core.csproj" because it was not found.
> Skipping project "C:\Creator.Components\Creator.Components.csproj"
> because it was not found.   Skipping project
> "C:\LC.Components.Core\LC.Components.Core.csproj" because it was not
> found.   Skipping project "C:\LC.Components\LC.Components.csproj"
> because it was not found.   Restored C:\app\creator.demo.csproj (in
> 282 ms).

Comment: Where is this DockerFile exist? is it in the same folder where these .csproj files you asking to copy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a Docker image from a multi project dot net core solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725916/building-a-docker-image-from-a-multi-project-dot-net-core-solution)

Answer (score 12):

Is complicated to explaind, why is not posible to build Dockerfile from same project space, then I read this article
[blog]: https://josiahmortenson.dev/blog/2020-06-08-aspnetcore-docker-https
and finaly understud how I need to run the build.

In my case:

```
/src
 .sln
 /project1
   project1.csproj
   Dockerfile
 /project2
   project2.csproj
   Dockerfile
 /reference1
   reference1.csproj
 /reference2
   reference2.csproj
```

Is necesary to move to /src level for run command

```
docker build -t {nametagedcontainer} -f project1/Dockerfile .
```

Finally

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS c
WORKDIR /app   

    
COPY ["project1/project1.csproj", "project1/"]
COPY ["reference1/reference1.csproj", "reference1/"]
#others reference if necesary



RUN dotnet restore "project1/project1.csproj" 

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/app/project1"
RUN dotnet build "project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

from c as publish
RUN dotnet publish "project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "{dllname}.dll"]
```