# Build docker container from solution with multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core

I have a .NET Core project that contained 2 projects:

```
SLN: 
     - Web-API
     - Infrastructure
```

I was building it with docker using this dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/Lab/out/API.dll"]
```

But now I have created a Web application as well in my solution

```
SLN:
 - Web-API
 - Web-App
 - Infrastructure
```

Suddenly, docker isn't building anymore. How come?
How can I create two docker containers based on the same solution one for the Web-API and one for the Web-app?

**Error message** from Docker:

The "GetDotNetHost" task could not be loaded from the assembly /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation/2.0.3/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Tasks.dll. Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/app/Lab/API.csproj]

Comment: how do you build? seems this isn't docker error

Comment: I build using Docker Build with the Dockerfile displayed above.. if I remove the Web-API project or remove the Web-App project the build works, but when I have both of them in the solution, the build fails.

Comment: If you're using docker-compose file in VS 2017, open a command line on the solution directory and try docker-compose down. Also try cleaning the solution and rebuilding. From your description, to me it looks like you're using the VS2017 built in docker support, it can be flaky. Especially if docker asks questions, VS wont allow you to answer them.

Comment: sorry, again, this is something coming from your IDE, the error message isn't from docker

Comment: Nop, using Visual Studio for Mac and Docker build directly from command prompt

Comment: can you open cmd or powershell and build that image?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: I only use cmd to build the image, dont use Visual Studio..

Comment: is it `docker build .` ?

Comment: yes, exactly.  docker build  .

Comment: I'm guessing, this is from the run command `RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out`, just for sake of finding the issue, you can comment this line and try again

Comment: That correct @vitr! It works without using the RUN command.
So it is something wrong when build it from the command? Strange thing is that I can build it in visual studio without any problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net core 2.0 - multiple projects solution docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103570/asp-net-core-2-0-multiple-projects-solution-docker-file)

Answer (score 1):

So this problem is now finally fixed. It actually turned out it was a problem while compiling a .net core 2.0 project when having Razor views available:

> Razor view precompilation is currently unavailable when performing a
>   self-contained deployment (SCD) in ASP.NET Core 2.0. The feature will
>   be available for SCDs when 2.1 releases. For more information, see
>   View compilation fails when cross-compiling for Linux on Windows.

What I needed to do was to add the nuget package:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation

in my project to make it work. Strange thing was that it was building inside visual studio for Mac but not from the command prompt.