# How to dockerize one main .NET Core project that uses two other projects?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, blazor, xaf

[Blazor app and class libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpwEp.png)

I am using DevExpress Xaf Framework. I want to dockerize its Blazor project with two other module projects. I researched how to dockerize more than one relational projects but I couldn't find anything. I have published three projects using Visual Studio into separate folders and created one dockerfile as below. Then ran it on command line with Docker commands but it did not work.

[docker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQt0C.png)

Also when I published the Blazor app into folder, the folder contained all the project files including dll file but when I tried to publish other two projects, their folder contained only `.nupkg` files as below.

[Blazor project's publish folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB9Wa.png)

[Other two project's publish folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuqNl.png)

Answer (score 0):

a container should only have one entrypoint, in your case it would be the server dll. The other two projects are required to build. Here is a link for a dockerfile with multiple projects, hope that helps:

[asp.net core 2.0 - multiple projects solution docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103570/asp-net-core-2-0-multiple-projects-solution-docker-file)